# CSS3 Transitions in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, transition

I've just noticed that some CSS3 transitions have stopped working in Chrome (was working when I checked a few weeks ago) - seems fine in Safari.
I've definitely used this code before but maybe i'm overlooking something this time around?

The aim is just to have a smooth transition on hover:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeDre/UGAu3/2/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
         div{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;

-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;     
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;     
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
transition-duration: 0.3s;     
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

div:hover{
    right:-10px;
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;

-webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;     
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;     
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
transition-duration: 0.3s;     
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 3):

`right` doesn't work on `static` positioned element, you need to use `position: relative;` on load as well as you need to define `right` and set it to `0` or whatever you like.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UGAu3/5/)

```
div{
    /* All the properties you have declared will go here plus === */
    right:0; /* Add this */
    position:relative; /* Add this */
}
```

---

Using `position: relative;` on load will help you transit your element on mouse out as well as on mouse over, so if you are setting `position: relative;` on `:hover` then your element will fail to transit on mouse out.

Also, I've noticed that you are not using any standard property for `transition` so make sure you use them.

Comment: Having declared `position:relative` on the main div (unhovered) it can now be removed from the hover state. Just a smidge less CSS weight. :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien & Paulie_D Perfect! thank you... I guess Google have tightened up their validation - time to check on my old sites :)

Comment: @MikeDre FYI, it fails on firefox as well